# Remove Caption and next/previous arrows from Colorbox for Node

Tags: 7, javascript

To display Node in Modal, I am using [colorbox node module](https://drupal.org/project/colorbox_node)

I changed the settings in Colorbox module to not display any information like Current, Next, Previous, etc. like: [image: Colorbox module settings]

however I can still see that small arrow and node count as shown in the picture below: [image: Colorbox node modal display]

How do I remove these small arrows and count overall and only have that Cross(X) to close the Modal.

**Edit**: I cleared the cache and this 4 of 41 is gone... but those arrows are still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in the latest DEV version.

Comment: which dev version? colorbox or colorbox node ?

Comment: oh I tried, and yes I could do that using latest colorbox_node dev version. Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

> The only way I found to do this was to change my theme css file (I use an Omega >theme so used global.css) and add:
>
> #cboxPrevious, #cboxNext {
>         width:0;
>      }
>
> I initially tried display:none but something is overriding it.

display:none works if you use !important